# how we can send email with multiple email account as sender

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send email with some accounts to some targets.But when use this code all emails are delivered to first sender account only.

from() just change name of sender in message and it could not change sender account

```
while(true)
{
$config = array(
            'driver' => 'smtp',
            'host' => $smtp,
            'from' => array('address' => $senders[$p], 'name' => 
  $senderName),
            'username' => $senders[$p],
            'password' => $senderpasses[$p],
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls'
        );        
   Config::set('mail', $config);
            $data = [
                'target' => $email[$m],
                'text' => $text,
                'title' => $title,
                'sender' => $senders[$p],
                'senderName' => $senderName
            ];

            try {
                Mail::send('emails.mail', ['data' => $data], function 
   ($message) use ($data) {
                    $message->from($data['sender'], $data['senderName']);
                    $message->to($data['target'])- 
   >subject($data['titl']);
                });
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
           $m++;
           $p++;
        if ($p >= count($senders)) {
            $p = 0;
        }
        if ($m >= count($email)) {
             return ($m);
        }
    }
```

it send email just with first sender and other users are not used.

Comment: In each iteration, you increase `$p` and `$m` - is this intended? So you send the first message with the first sender, the second one with the second sender and so on. To send the same email multiple times, your code would require it to exist as a duplicate in the `$email` array.
Even though I cannot see the purpose, you can try to use a nested loop instead.

Comment: this code send first and second email by first sender just.:///                                          Just name of sender changed and sender username stay as first sender username.

Answer (score 0):

Emails are, by definition, sent from a *single* sender to *multiple* addresses, so it is not possible to achieve what you are asking for.

You have to send the mail multiple times, one for each sender. May I ask you what is the purpose of this scenario?

Comment: One can use multiple "FROM" addresses per Mail, however. (Cf. RFC822, RFC2822, RFC5322).

Comment: from just change "name" of sender in the email that will be delivered.I want change the sender account